# Desktop responsivess React + StyledComponent

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How do you do css responsivess to desktop app using react + styled components.

I using vw, vh, % ,em css techs...

Comment: Care to expand a little?

Do you want to create custom styled components that are responsive using those attributes?

Any code examples that you can provide us with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.